# object prototype function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

Can i not use Object prototype this way?

```
Object.prototype.keyPressed = function(){
        var key = (this.keyCode ? this.keyCode : this.which);
        return key;
};


$(document).on('keypress'), function(e){
    if (e.keyPressed() != 13) return;
});
```

Comment: Open your browser's console window to easily see typos that you may not otherwise catch.

Comment: TYPO! - http://jsfiddle.net/zVzX8/

Comment: You can, even though I personally would do it differently. Having a free-standing function (which takes an event object as argument) results in clearer code, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, but you have a syntax error:

```
$(document).on('keypress'), function(e){
    if (e.keyPressed() != 13) return;
});
```

should be

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.keyPressed() != 13) return;
});
```

Note the extra `)` after `'keypress'`.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fuDKF/)